# Where is Arqade Meta connect to?

Tags: discussion, meta

It seems not to be connected to Meta Stackoverflow.

It is somehow connected to Arqade but I cannot see my meta questions, activity, answers in my profile  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/61839/esq

Also do I get reputation for Arqade or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What meta is, and how it works is all explained in the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

This site is the meta site *of* Arqade. It has its own separate questions, but your rep here is your rep on Arqade. You do not gain or lose rep for votes here. From the Help Center article:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Arqade (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

With regards to Meta Stack Overflow, that situation is [changing soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own), with Meta Stack Overflow to become as this site is to Arqade, and a new Meta Stack Exchange created for questions relating to the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

This site (Arqade Meta) is, what we call in SE network, a child-meta. You earn no reputation and the reputation here is the same as on Arqade. Your profile is mostly inherited from the main site as well, but all the activities in your profile are independent.

Stack Overflow's Meta is different as it's also the meta for the whole network in addition to being Stack Overflow's site-meta, but that's about to change with Meta Stack Exchange.